# Why all attributes in the access_config becomes require while the documentation said they are optional?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am new to Terraform and its CDK. I am confuse about the following:

When I try to run the `tf.json` generated through `cdktf synth` using `cdktf deploy`, `terraform plan` or `terraform apply`, the console keeps telling me that all attributes inside the `access_config` are required and emit errors, but I checked the [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_instance#nested_access_config), it is said that these field can be optional.

So, I want to know is it a bug or the documentation is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discuss with my colleagues, I managed to solve the problem. For the `access_config`, you have to fill in the attributes while leave them blank if you don't want to give any value to them:

```json
"access_config":[{
    "nat_ip":"google_compute_address.some_name.address",
    "public_ptr_domain_name":"",
    "network_tier":""
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are checking the correct version of Terraform documentation and still see in tf plan/apply these attributes as required then you should add these attributes in your config. Might happen that the documentation is not up to date

Comment: However, if i just put the `access_config{}` into the `network_interface` of the google compute instance like:

```
"google_compute_instace" "instace"{
    # ... just skip the basic things such as the name, machinetype and the boot disk, etc.
    network_interface{
        access_config{}
    }
}
```

it will work, the instance will gain the public ephemeral address, though what i want to do in the question is to assign a static ip address to the instance.

Answer (score 0):

The use for access_config is required in terraform cdk in comparison to terraform hcl. In terraform where we use HCL to write the configurations,
access_config can be left empty but for terraform cdk is needs to be populated with parameters which can be left empty.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).